# Ruby cannot find required libraries even though gem is installed

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, require

I have spent literally days trying to install ruby 1.9.2 and get it working with gems :-/ I eventually gave up on my Mac OSX 10.6 machine and below is the current state on my Ubuntu machine. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
# ruby test.rb
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- mongo (LoadError)
 from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
 from test.rb:1:in `<main>'
# cat test.rb
require 'mongo'
db = Mongo::Connection.new.db("mydb")
# gem which mongo
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/mongo-1.1.2/lib/mongo.rb
# cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=maverick
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.10"
```

According to this page: http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/19
I symlinked which ruby I was using to match that which gem is using:

```
# which ruby
/usr/local/rvm/bin/ruby
# ls -l `which ruby`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 2010-11-17 13:25 /usr/local/rvm/bin/ruby -> /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby
# gem env | grep 'RUBY EXECUTABLE'
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby
# which gem
/usr/local/rvm/bin/gem
# gem -v
1.3.7
# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i686-linux]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with the word. Is this what you mean: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gadol ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is "rvm" displaying in your `/usr/local/rvm/` path? Did you do a system-wide install, as a system administrator using [administering Ruby system wide](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/deployment/system-wide/) for multiple users?

Did you add `[[ -s '/usr/local/lib/rvm' ]] && source '/usr/local/lib/rvm'` to your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` (whichever you have configured)?

For normal, every day use, I recommend RVM's default setup:
[RVM installation](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/), [RVM gems management](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/).

Note to self: Buy stock in RVM. It's too cool.

Answer (score 6):

Try putting the following line at the beginning

```
require "rubygems"
```

Comment: That's not needed in Ruby 1.9.2, which he's running.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work under Ruby 1.8.7, which is pre-installed by default on OS X?

If so, one difference between 1.9.1 and 1.9.2 is that `"."` isn't part of `$:`'s path any more.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you do `rvm implode` and delete the current setup. Then use the [railsready](https://github.com/joshfng/railsready) script to setup RVM and Ruby properly for you on Ubuntu. It's important to understand that until you know what you are doing you should run the script as a user.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

On linux and OS X, I have always had to put require "rubygems" in the beginning. However it has always worked fine without this line on windows.

Comment: `require rubygems` was needed in Ruby < 1.9. It's now done automatically in 1.9+.