# Ruby cannot find gem in gemset

Tags: rvm, jruby, xml-simple

I apologize if I've missed something obvious. I am new to Ruby.

My overall goal is to add functionality to an existing script, which is using `rvm` and gemsets.

When I install new gems to a particular gemset, the `require`s in my scripts fail to find them. I am using the following rvm instance:

```
$ rvm current
jruby-1.6.7.2@preflight
```

To confirm:

```
$ which ruby
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.7.2/bin/ruby
$ ruby -v
jruby 1.6.7.2 (ruby-1.8.7-p357) (2012-05-01 26e08ba) (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_11) [darwin-x86_64-java]
```

I specified the gemset into I install a given gem (let's say `xml-simple`).

```
$ rvm @preflight do gem install xml-simple
Successfully installed xml-simple-1.1.5
1 gem installed
```

To verify the gem installed correctly:

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***
...
xml-simple (1.1.5)
...
```

We see the module I installed there.

Following [the xml-simple instructions](http://xml-simple.rubyforge.org/) to include the module, I run this script:

`require 'xmlsimple'`

which, results in:

```
$ ruby testver.rb
LoadError: no such file to load -- xmlsimple
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1033
   (root) at testver.rb:1
```

One suspicious thing I have seen is that printing out `RUBY_VERSION` and `$LOAD_PATH` shows me this:

```
$ ruby testver.rb
1.8.7
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/1.8
.
```

Comment: Just as a finished this post, I encountered a solution from another post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4209569/1258020. Adding ``equire "rubygems"`` worked. Writing out the question at least allowed me to focus in on the problem point. Sort of rubber-duckying.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `require "rubygems"` is required prior to Ruby version 1.9.2, [per this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4209569/1258020). This resolved my issue.